# Ping/Pong frames in MessageWebSocket

Tags: c#, websocket, uwp

I built an app on UWP and am using wss connection by `MessageWebSocket`.
How can In use `MessageWebSocket`, and send "custom" frames(OpCodes). Like a ping/pong?